# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

VS Code is not running in the browser, throwing the below error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)

I have tried all the necessary  settings, reinstalled the VS Code, extensions, firewall, etc.

Extension version: 5.7.9
VS Code version: Code 1.78.0 (252e5463d60e63238250799aef7375787f68b4ee, 2023-05-03T20:09:00.748Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Live server is not working in the browser – I'm not able to work without it.